# Can you identify this model of a yellow truck?

Tags: technic, set-identification

It's part of a series of models I had as a kid that I want to take apart for my own kids now, and I'm looking for the original instructions.

Can you identify this one?

[image: yellow truck]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This model is built from set [8062-1: Universal Set with Storage Case](http://brickset.com/sets/8062-1/Briefcase-Set).
Inventory and building instructions are available **[here](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/8062-1)**.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! Do you have any tricks or dedicated search engine to identify them, or do you just remember?

Comment: From the size and style of the model, I felt it could be a model from one universal box. A quick browse in the proper section of peeron database gave the answer... Other useful databases are Brickset http://brickset.com/ (among other things it lists official building instructions from modern sets) and Bricklink http://www.bricklink.com/. Old building instructions are available here too: http://www.brickfactory.info/